# How to display progress of Ant build?

Tags: java, ant

When running an Ant script with the **-logfile logFile** option, is it possible to still print out some very basic progress information? I would be delighted even with something as basic as printing '.' to standard out for every new target hit.

I've found the **splash** ant task which seems to be along the right lines, only I'm looking for something that's **not** graphical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be quite easy to implement this with an [Ant build listener](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html#buildevents).